# Sample data for community edition 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8, sample-data

I have installed the Magento community edition 1.8 as my hosting company refuses to upgrade the MySQL version to 5.6

I have installed the site properly, but i missed sample data, so i can understand how it all works.

Could anyone please tell me or give a link to sample data, along with any information on how to install this.

Answer (score 0):

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce18-ee113/ht_magento-ce-sample.data.html

you can get all info related to sample data in this site.

you just create new database
import this sql file
and use this database when you install magento

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this url to get the sample data. https://www.magentocommerce.com/download#download1759

1. create database
2. import the downloaded sample data's database i.e., sql file
3. Proceed to install

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed Magento then you need to reinstall it but this time with the new database which can be download from https://www.magentocommerce.com/download#download1759.

Steps:-

1. Download the sample data.
2. Create database
3. Import sample data into the database.
4. Start installation of Magento. In database configuration of Magento, you need to enter the name of the database which you have created.

Answer (score -3):

Chrisdevelop unfortunately this smaple data isn't available on magento anymore,you can get it from below links though,but if possible consider 1.9.3.1 and above that will do the better job.

1.Sample data:
http://mirror.gunah.eu/magento/sample-data/

2.Installation guide
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ycznlLY257U